# load dynamic menu from database to toolstrip menu with images

Tags: c#

i am working on a project where i have to create menu items from database on run time at form load in c# windows form application, I have created the menu but now the problem is i have to display the icon along  the menu from the database,i have searched over the interned but didn't fine anything suitable so if any one know please guide me how to do it. thanks in advance

```
    private void toolstripform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        StatusStrip sst = new StatusStrip();
        this.Controls.Add(toolStrip2);
        this.Controls.Add(toolStrip1);
        string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT TOP 3 [MAINMNU],[MENUPARVAL] FROM [Sales_db].[dbo].[MNU_PARENT]");
        DataTable dt = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);
        string slctcmd1 = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MNU_PARENT where MENUPARVAL = '4' or MENUPARVAL = '5' or MENUPARVAL = '6' or MENUPARVAL = '7'");
        DataTable dt1 = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd1);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem MnuStripItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["MAINMNU"].ToString());
            SubMenu(MnuStripItem, dr["MENUPARVAL"].ToString());
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(MnuStripItem);
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem topmenu = new    ToolStripMenuItem(dr["MAINMNU"].ToString());

            toolStrip2.Items.Add(topmenu);

        }


    }
    public void SubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem mnu, string submenu)
    {
        string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT ID,FRM_NAME FROM MNU_SUBMENU WHERE MENUPARVAL='" + submenu + "'");
        DataTable dt = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);



        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem SSMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["FRM_NAME"].ToString(), null, new EventHandler(ChildClick));
            Sub_SubMenu(SSMenu, dr["ID"].ToString());
            mnu.DropDownItems.Add(SSMenu);
        }
    }

    public void Sub_SubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem S_Sub_Menu, string s_s_menu)
    {
        string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT Listitems FROM SubMenu WHERE SubMenuID='" + s_s_menu + "'");
        DataTable dt = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);



        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem SSMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["Listitems"].ToString());
            S_Sub_Menu.DropDownItems.Add(SSMenu);
        }
    }
   private void ChildClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT FRM_CODE FROM MNU_SUBMENU WHERE FRM_NAME= '" + sender.ToString() + "'");
        DataTable dtransaction = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);

        Assembly frmAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath);
        foreach (Type type in frmAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.BaseType == typeof(Form))
            {
                if (type.Name == dtransaction.Rows[0][0].ToString())
                {
                    Form frmShow = (Form)frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString());

                    foreach (Form form in this.MdiChildren)
                    {
                        form.Close();
                    }

                    frmShow.MdiParent = this;
                    frmShow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                    frmShow.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: Are you asking how to store an image in the db?  Or are you asking for the C# code to include the image on the context menu?

Comment: What did you search for? There's a lot of documentation, code and samples that shows how to use icons in menus, even dynamically loaded icons. There are also a lot of docs, code and samples that show how to load a blob from a database. The same for creating an icon from a blob (ie byte array).

Comment: @destination-data  . i am looking for the c# code that include the image  along with menu from database

Comment: Ok.  Can you share the code you already have?  The section that adds the menu.

Comment: @destination-data.. i have included the code